# Ruby: tap writes on a read?

Tags: ruby

So if I understand correctly Object#tap uses yield to produce a temporary object to work with during the execution of a process or method. From what I think I know about yield, it does something like, yield takes (thing) and gives (thing).dup to the block attached to the method it's being used in?
But when I do this:

```
class Klass
attr_accessor :hash
  def initialize
   @hash={'key' => 'value'}
  end
end

instance=Klass.new
instance.instance_variable_get('@hash')[key] # => 'value', as it should

instance.instance_variable_get('@hash').tap {|pipe| pipe['key']=newvalue}

instance.instance_variable_get('@hash')[key] # => new value... wut?
```

I was under the impression that yield -> new_obj. I don't know how correct this is though, I tried to look it up on ruby-doc, but Enumerator::yielder is empty, yield(proc) isn't there, and the fiber version... I don't have any fibers, in fact, doesn't Ruby actually explicitly require include 'fiber' to use them?

So what ought have been a read method on the instance variable and a write on the temp is instead a read/write on the instance variable... which is cool, because that's what I was trying to do and accidentally found when I was looking up a way to deal with hashes as instance variables (for some larger-than-I'm-used-to tables for named arrays of variables), but now I'm slightly confused, and I can't find a description of the mechanism that's making this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object#tap` couldn't be simpler:

```
VALUE
rb_obj_tap(VALUE obj)
{
    rb_yield(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

(from the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap)). It just yields and then returns the receiver. A quick check in IRB shows that `yield` yields the object itself rather than a new object.

```
def foo
  x = {}
  yield x
  x
end

foo { |y| y['key'] = :new_value }
# => {"key" => :new_value }
```

So the behavior of `tap` is consistent with `yield`, as we would hope.

Answer (score 0):

`tap` does not duplicate the receiver. The block variable is assigned the very receiver itself. Then, `tap` returns the receiver. So when you do `tap{|pipe| pipe['key']=newvalue}`, the receiver of `tap` is modified. To my understanding,

```
x.tap{|x| foo(x)}
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo(x); x
```

and

```
y.tap{|y| y.bar}
```

is equivalent to:

```
y.bar; y
```